# normalization command before using classifier in matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, classification, data-mining

I am using normalization command:

> ```
> normA = Xtrain - min(Xtrain(:));
>  Xtrain = normA ./ max(normA(:));
>   normB = Xtest - min(Xtest(:));
>  Xtest = normB ./ max(normB(:));
> ```

to normalized my data before using classifier (design tree), but every time I got very poor accuracy, it is around 55.00. Meanwhile, I got accuracy 93.88 without using the normalization algorithm. can anyone tell me what the problem exactly and what I have to do?

**This is my code:**

```
 load('train_and_test_data.mat')
     Xtrain= Xtrain(:, 2:42);
     Xtest= Xtest(:,2:42);

     normA = Xtrain - min(Xtrain(:));
     Xtrain = normA ./ max(normA(:));


      normB = Xtest - min(Xtest(:));
     Xtest = normB ./ max(normB(:));


    Mdl = fitctree(Xtrain ,Ytrain);

    y =Mdl.predict(Xtest); %test


    Conf_Mat = confusionmat(Ytest,y)
```

This small sample of data I am using before normalization:

```
1   0   0   0   0
17  4   2   2   0
38  20  17  0   0
11  2   2   0   0
2   1   1   0   0
11  1   4   0   0
8   5   1   1   1
21  1   16  0   0
27  12  11  0   0
13  11  2   1   0
12  3   2   2   1
```

Comment: What type of data do you use?

Comment: I am using numeric data

Comment: Decision trees shouldn't be affected by normalization. In this case the difference might be because of numeric precision but it seems highly unlikely. If you don't find the reason I would suggest simply using the un-normalized version.

Comment: I tried with:
Naive Bayes; 
SVM ;
Neural Network;  
Ensemble of decision trees;
But also I get the same problem.

Comment: You could try to understand how the distribution of the data changes after the normalization, try to hash all the data and see if you get repeated results etc. to rule out numeric precision problems. Note that all of the methods you've mentions except for decision trees could be effected by normalization so their different results are not surprising.

Answer (score 0):

You are not normalizing the training and the test set using the same transformation.

```
 normA = Xtrain - min(Xtrain(:));
 Xtrain = normA ./ max(normA(:));

 normB = Xtest - min(Xtest(:));
 Xtest = normB ./ max(normB(:));
```

Subtracting a different amount.  Dividing by a different amount. Therefore the inputs from your test set are not comparable to the inputs from your training set.  Instead, normalize your test data using the *same* transformation.

```
 normB = Xtest - min(Xtrain(:));
 Xtest = normB ./ max(normA(:));
```